# iterations of $f(x)=\dfrac{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e}{a'x^3+b'x^2+c'x+d'}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, iterated-function-system

About iterated functions I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) that for example for $f(x)=Cx+D$ we can calculate quite simply that:

$f^{[n]}(x)=C^nx+\dfrac{1-C^n}{1-C}D$

Likewise, I would like to obtain an explicit expression for the following function which is a fraction of two polynomials, and the denominator has a smaller order by one.

$f(x)=\dfrac{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e}{a'x^3+b'x^2+c'x+d'}$

Is it possible to apply the same procedure for $f(x)$ here? Will that help if we assume $b,c,e, b', c'=0$? That is:

$f(x)=\dfrac{ax^4+dx}{a'x^3+d'}$.

If it is not possible to obtain an explicit expression for $f(x)$ Is there a known numeric algorithm through which I can quickly calculate $f^{[n]}(x)$ for large $n$?

Comment: I don't know. I would suggest trying to start with an easier case, for instance $f(x)=(ax^2+bx+c)/(a'x+b)$, compute $f^{[n]}$ explicitly and try to look for a pattern

Comment: However, this reminds me the Mobius transformations and the fact that there is a nice way of composing them seeing them as 2x2 matrices. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation for the definition, and the section "Projective matrix representations" for how to treat the composition of two such functions

Comment: Oh thanks, I will check that

Comment: I was thinking about this and I think I have some sort of idea, but there is a problem that you might want to consider. While for $f$ of the form $f(x)=(Ax+B)/(Cx+D)$ (a Mobius function) we obtain $f^{[n]}$ that is again a Mobius function, for higher degree rational functions, as the one in your question, the iterated function $f^{[n]}$ might in general have high degree polynomials in the numerator and denominator. This also means a lot of terms in its expression

Comment: By a lot of terms you mean how many? like a hundred terms? A thousand? Will that make it computationally infeasible?

Comment: At most $4n+1$ terms in the numerator, and similarly for the denominator. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

One can try to proceed in a way similar to that of the Möbius transformations
$$ f(x)=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}. $$
For what follows, one must know the definition of projective space over $\mathbb R$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space). In the second part of the answer, I try not to mention projective spaces.

So, let's consider a rational function of the form
$$ f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}, $$
where $P,Q$ are polynomials of degree at most $k$. This function can be extended to the projective line $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)$ as follows:
$$ F([x,y]):=[\tilde P(x,y),\tilde Q(x,y)], $$
where $\tilde P(x,y)=y^k P(x/y)$, $\tilde Q(x,y)=y^k Q(x/y)$. This is an extension of $f$ in the sense that
$$ F([x,1])=[f(x),1]\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R \quad\text{s.t. $Q(x)\neq 0$}$$

From this, if we want to compute $f^{[n]}$, we can reduce ourselves to compute $F^{[n]}$. Namely,
$$ F^{[n]}([x,1])=[f^{[n]}(x),1] \quad \forall x\in\mathbb R \quad\text{s.t. $Q(x)\neq 0$}.$$

---

In practice, what does it mean? (From here, one doesn't need to know the definition of projective space). Let's take your function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{ax^4+dx}{a'x^3+d'}.$$
Let's define $\tilde P, \tilde Q$ and $F$ as above, namely (choosing $k=4$ as it is the maximum degree of the two polynomials):
$$ F([x,y])=[{ax^4+dxy^3},{a'x^3y+d'y^4}].$$
Now, let's compute iteritevly $F^{[n]}$ (just considering it as a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself). Since we are composing polynomials, $F^{[n]}$ must be of the form
$$ F^{[n]}([x,y])=[P_n(x,y),Q_n(x,y)], $$
with $P_n$ and $Q_n$ polynomials of degree at most $kn$. For instance,
$$ P_2(x,y)=\tilde P(\tilde P(x,y),\tilde Q(x,y))=a(ax^4+dxy^3)^4+d(ax^4+dxy^3)(a'x^3y+d'y^4)^3.$$
Then, you will obtain $f^{[n]}$ simply taking
$$ f^{[n]}(x)=\frac {P_n(x,1)}{Q_n(x,1)} $$

So, as long as you have an efficien way of composing polynomials (numerically for instance), you have a way of writing $f^{[n]}$. As I said in previous comments, though, the degree of $P_n$ and $Q_n$ might grow dramatically as $n$ grows, namely the degree will be at most $kn$, in your case $4n$.

Comment: Having some knowledge of coding, I think one can compute the coefficients of $P_n$ and $Q_n$ using a recursive algorithm. The only constraint is that, if one wants to compute, say, $f^{[100]}$, one has to allow polynomials of degree 400, and I don't think there is an easy way to simplify the expression.

Comment: I wishe there was an easier way.

Comment: What about $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$? Does this have a simple solution like that of $f(x)=Cx+D$

Comment: I ask this because I thought there might be a solution that has constant number of terms regardless $n$. Like in $f(x)=Cx+D$ the number of terms in $f^{[n]}(x)$ is 3 no matter what $n$ is.

Comment: I don't know if there is an easier way. If $f$ is a second degree polynomial, there might be an easy way to calculate the coefficients through matrix composition, I don't know. Even if it's not the case, there should be a way to obtain a formula. However, without any doubt, $f^{[n]}$ will have degree $2n$.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I fear that is a very lucky case, as composition of degree 1 polynomials is still a degree 1 polynomial. Now, being completely honest, since the rational function in your example is of the form "deg4/deg3", for large $x$ it should behave as a polynomial of degree 1, so it could also happen that the expression above might be simplified into something that has bounded degree (independent from n). But if I had to guess, I don't think it is true